# Why is RMSE inappropriate for Poisson distribution?

Tags: random-forest, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression, rms, deviance

I want to build models to predict the number of car claims which follow a Poisson distribution (mean = 0.05).

One model is a Poisson regression and another is a RandomForest and I want to compare the accuracy on a validation test.

**Questions:**

- I heard that RMSE is inappropriate to measure the accuracy of a Poisson distribution. Why ?
- I heard Deviance (-2 Log likelihood) is commonly used as an accuracy metric for the Poisson Regression but how can I compute a Deviance for the RandomForest  since the concept of Log likelihood doesn't apply to RandomForests?

Comment: Do yoi have a citation for your first claim? One reason not to use RMSE is that the poisson distribution do not have a constant variance, so interpretation is difficult. But if the use is to compare poisson regression and randomforrest models on the same data, it could well be OK. But also make residual plots!